# Laravel 4.2 check attachment existence

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-4, attachment

I have the following code:

```
$message->to($user->W_EMAIL_ADDRESS, '')
        ->subject($user->W_SUBJECT.$user->W_SITE_ADDRESS);
```

Is there any possible way to check the existence of the file before put the following line?

```
$message->attach($user->W_PATH_FILE);
```

many thanks

Comment: can you not check if $user->W_PATH_FILE is not empty you then add the line $message->attach($user->W_PATH_FILE); to the $message object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at filesystem functions that PHP offers here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

You can check if a given file exists and is readable by PHP with the following:

```
if(is_readable($user->W_PATH_FILE)) {
  $message->attach($user->W_PATH_FILE);
}
```